# AngularJS filter out a string from bad data.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filtering

I am using a tool to get some data from amazon. 
When I drill down to the data I need in angular it works. My code is:

```
<div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div ng-repeat="item in store.items">
        <a ng-href="{{item.ItemLinks[0].ItemLink[0].URL}}">{{item.ItemAttributes[0].Title[0]}}</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And the href that gets rendered looks like this: `href="["www.example.com"]"`
Is there a way to remove the `["` and the `"]` from the string and have it work with the ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `item.ItemLinks[0].ItemLink[0].URL` is an Array of length 1, rather than a string. When angular evaluates it, it will convert it to a string, adding those characters.

Try `{{item.ItemLinks[0].ItemLink[0].URL[0]}}` to use the string directly, rather than a string representation of the Array.

Comment: Thank you!! I guess I should have noticed that because they were not showing up in the title. I will accept your answer as soon as stack overflow lets me :)